# Looking to return the data from the 1st of August 2018 until 5 days beyond today

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following line of code in my query:

```
AND dateadd(dd,0,datediff(dd,0,tr.STARTDATE)) BETWEEN GETDATE()-10 AND
    CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE()+5, 126)#(lf)--
```

Instead of returning the last 10 days and the next 5, I am looking to amend the query to return data from the 1st of August 2018 until 5 days beyond today...

Thanks in advance.. Sorry i am very new to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
WHERE tr.STARTDATE >= '2018-08-01' AND
      tr.STARTDATE < DATEADD(day, 6, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

This `WHERE` clause would match all records where `STARTDATE` occurs on midnight of 1st August 2018, or on or earlier than 5 days from the current date.

Comment: Typo, you forgot the `AND/OR`

Comment: @CoderofCode I must be getting old or something.